# Declare Vec2 as a Vector?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

4 of cocos2d-x on eclipse for android. I'm trying to declare a std::Vector as a Vec2 like this.

```
Vector<Vec2*> _Positions;
```

But I'm getting various errors like "base opperand '->' has non-pointer type 'cocos2d::Vector' ", "static assertion failed: Invalid Type for cococs2d::Vector!", "'class cocos2d::Vec2' has no member named release", etc.

Is it really not possible to declare a vector with Vec2? If no is there a way to store Vec2's as an array?

Thank you for your time. :D

Comment: You probably imported cocos2d.Vector and not java.util.Vector

Comment: Yeah I'm using cocos2d Vec2 as well. I just have USING_NS_CC up hence no cocos2d::

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a `std::vector` of Vec2's.  I think what you are looking for is as follows:

```
std::vector <Vec2 *> _Positions;
```

Notice the case of the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Vec2 is not inherited class of cocos2d::Node.
Hence, can not be Vectorize using cocos2d::Vector.

Vec2 is struct type and you are meant to use std::Vector from `#include <vector>`.

Code Example (as given by microslop) :

```
 std::vector <cocos2d::Vec2> _Positions;
```

Other Samples:

```
std::vector<cocos2d::Vec2> a;
std::vector<cocos2d::Vec2>::const_iterator i;
a.push_back(1);
for(i=a.begin(); i!=a.end(); ++i){
  cocos2d::log("%f %f",(*i).x,(*i).y);
}
```